# Disable the HTML button centering of inner elements

Tags: html, css

Considering this example: http://jsfiddle.net/afkjnzss/ , is it possible to override the `button` styles that make its inner content (the `div` in the example) go center **(vertically)**?

Basically, I want it to behave like a regular `div` but using a `button`. The inner content should be placed starting from the top. I'm looking for a generic solution.

**Reason:** I'm using a `button` because I need the `[disabled]` attribute, which apparently works only on form elements. Also, using `pointer-events: none` is not an option, because I need to support IE9+.

Comment: If you're adding an user interface element just so you can stick `disabled` on something that can't normally be disabled, then you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: It's a button within a ribbon bar. I wouldn't normally worry about state-of-the-art HTML, that's why I would've used a div or anchor tag instead. But in this case, I need a button because of the aforementioned condition.

Comment: This seems to happen a lot lately - please, just please, try to ask for more information should something not be very clear. It's better instead of just voting to close a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` elements are replaced elements, so their representation is outside the scope of CSS.

So, instead of not centering the contents, I suggest using a wrapper (e.g. `.text`) inside the button which fills it all. This way it won't matter if the wrapper is centered, because they have the same height.

```css
#button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;    
}
#button > .text {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  <div class="text">blabla</div>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: after editing question its more clear what do you want, maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/afkjnzss/2/)?

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#button{
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```